# Combing global class names with component specific style

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components, emotion

I'm building a design system where I put emphasis on the architecture - I want it to be a good developer experience.

Bootstrap is used in this system but also together with component-specific styles. I'm thinking I want `CSS-in-JS` because I like to write style in the actual component, not in a different CSS file.

I have an idea, something like this:

```
const componentSpecificStyle = `margin-bottom: 0rem;`  

const globalBootstrapClass = ['card', 'card-body']

return <div someArgument={componentSpecificStyle + globalBootstrapClass} />
```

This way it would be standard, two types of classes, one argument on the element, less confusion for coming developers.

### What I've tried

1. Looked into `Styled-Components` and `Emotion`, from what I can tell they don't help me achieve this. It's possible to do

```
const Component = styled.div`margin-bottom: 0rem;`

return <Component className={'card card-body'}
```

But it seems a bit clumsy to me.

2. `React-Bootstrap` would be a solution for this but I think I usually end up adding extra classnames anyway, so I won't abstract that away...

ex.

```
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'

const componentSpecificStyle = `margin-bottom: 0rem;`

return <Card.body style={{componentSpecificStyle}} />
```

or something similar... but as I said, what if I want to add another classname on top of this? then we are styling in three different ways, `react-bootstrap`, inline-ish `style` and `className`.

### Question

Am I making it unnecessarily complex?

Any suggestions or thoughts on the matter are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define CSS inside your components, you're going to need CSS-in-JS indeed.

Theoretically, you're allowed define inline styles like so:

```js
const style = {
  marginBottom: '0rem',
};

return <div style={style} />
```

but this doesn't scale well, all styles are inlined, and you don't get all the benefits of CSS-in-JS, like ability to use props, themes, style inheritance, and having your styles autoprefixed.

Example of what you've tried in pt 1 actually makes a lot of sense.

Maybe it isn't the *absolute best* idea to mix global class names with `styled-components`, so if you want to go all-in with `styled-components`, you could define some set of styles in `styled-components` only, and inherit them one in another, like so:

```
const Card = styled.div`
  /* Your card styles go here */
`;

const CardBody = styled(Card)`
  /* Your card body styles go here */
  /* (in your example you apply card and card-body to the same element, */
  /* so I assume card-body is a "variant" of card) */
`;

const Component = styled(CardBody)`
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
`;

return <Component />
```

This way, you have all your styles managed by `styled-components`, and you don't need to worry about global styles overwriting something you wrote in styled-components - because `Component` styles will be more important than `CardBody` styles, and `CardBody` styles will be more important than `Card` styles.

Comment: This is a great answer  I'm afraid I won't be able to go all in `styled-components` since I use Bootstrap and will have to apply their global classes such as `card` and `card-body`, classes imported elsewhere and not specified as `css` inside the component.

With your solution I could use the `<Component` and then `<Component className={'card card-body'} />` which is a solution I'm thinking of (well, the example 1 of what I tried, just like to referenced :)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've come up with so far is using `Emotion` and their css-prop on elements. https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop

This way I can write code like it's inline-css but the end result is a class on the element, which I think is neat.

Here's an example:

```
const styleEmployeeBox = css`border-right: black solid 1px;`
const bstyleCard = 'card';

...

return <div css={styleEmployeeBox} className={bstyleCard}>
```

Inspecting the element shows me:

```
<div class="card css-nrnevs-ComponentName">
```

Writing this kind of `css-in-js` is something I'm choosing to go with because I see a lot of developers in my team writing inlined style on the `style` prop -- probably because they are lazy and don't want to add a css-classes for small specific fixes.

---

If they are reasons to why I shouldn't go ahead with this solution, I'd be HAPPY to hear about it. :)

---